# Electron Configuration

Tags: code-golf, string, chemistry

> In [atomic physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_physic) and [quantum chemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chemistry), the **electron configuration** is the distribution of [electrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron) of an [atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom) in [atomic orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital). For example, the electron configuration of the neon atom is *1s<sup>2</sup> 2s<sup>2</sup> 2p<sup>6</sup>* <sub>(From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configuration))</sub>

### Challenge

Your challenge is to take a number representing the [atomic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_number) of an element and output the electron configuration of that element as defined by the [Aufbau principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle).

Iron (26) has the electron configuration `1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p6 3d6 4s2`. However, superscripts are unnecessary; the output for Iron (26) should be along the lines of `1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p6 3d6 4s2`.

### Specification

- You do not have to handle any inputs outside of the range `1 <= n <= 118`.
- Your output should look something like the test cases, but you may use any non-digit character/characters (aside from `s`, `p`, `d`, and `f`) to delimit the different orbitals.
- You must return/print a string containing the orbital names/values/delimiters; you cannot simply return/print an array.
- You do not need to handle any exceptions to the Aufbau principle; where there are exceptions, printing the "incorrect" configuration is fine.

Examples:

```
Input -> Valid output            -> Invalid output
16    -> 1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p4     -> 1s22s22p63s23p4
16    -> 1s2, 2s2, 2p6, 3s2, 3p4 -> [[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 6], [3, 2], [3, 4]]
17    -> 1s2+2s2+2p6+3s2+3p5     -> 1s2s2s2s2p6p3s2s3p5
```

Here is a list of all the electronic orbitals. The maximum values they can contain are below the name:

```
name: 1s 2s 2p 3s 3p 3d 4s 4p 4d 5s 5p 4f 5d 6s 6p 5f 6d 7s 7p
max:  2  2  6  2  6  10 2  6  10 2  6  14 10 2  6  14 10 2  6
```

### Test Cases

```
Input -> Output
1     -> 1s1
2     -> 1s2
16    -> 1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p4
50    -> 1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p6 3d10 4s2 4p6 4d10 5s2 5p2
115   -> 1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p6 3d10 4s2 4p6 4d10 5s2 5p6 4f14 5d10 6s2 6p6 5f14 6d10 7s2 7p3
```

Here is a [complete list](https://pastebin.com/raw/yGJ1cFSC) and a [reference implementation](https://github.com/aaronryank/minproj/blob/master/chemistry/electron-config.c) of sorts ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVPbboMwDH3PV1hMW8MGE/S2C233IWs1MQKtJQodpN2kil8fi8OldOrFqlL7OPGxc0JgL4OgLG8wCeKtCGGSS4Hp42rGDtDalytC2I0II0xC@Nqi5GkmMPFja@fHJswZnDSRwv5skgwj4BcrNLbJMJERN27zWwGG1WX3rjKEcbiGyRQc80o7mmkrg5Wf8d486V2pTZaFcpsll/cVZ7MFfK8wDoE7JmNqQkizT5R@zMm/p74tIHft/5hsr4twDZtgTwn12KGJOgUTGvQNuEqDDf5nXh8x4bU6UjC2S1FAkCYRLjWX3lAztFc2A9d9Ntm/URk7EkTMpT1TkugKdbIzyYdiDPP3BUxh37dA/cbN6jonvOG5qPD@l87f3Rdd16lzpBvcN8S5zCpaw80Ny@jrZaOWAXkD7Qm1DCkcUjikcEThSIcReYSNCRsTNiJsTNgTYU8bo@jMjFUfUZoBR0XteIBKDvdF/T88qNfX3mU7AlKLjep3WvHjm8OF6bXH6k/vMCAurE6pemdBClfPBhNOUrfSnmjS1U1Ooe84VZstW/M@VNmiLH@DKPaXeWnH6z8))

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code wins!

Comment: Can we output arrays? For instance, `50` would give `[[2], [2, 6], [2, 6, 10], [2, 6, 10], [2, 2]]`

Comment: IIRC every challenge that runs on a finite set of inputs with a constant output is a candidate for the kolmogorov tag. Nice challenge.

Comment: is [my output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150418/47120) format ok ?

Comment: In the test cases, `3d` seems to be filled before `4s`, `4d` before `5s`, `6s` after `4f` and `5d`, which violate the [Madelung rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufbau_principle#Madelung_energy_ordering_rule). Should we golf programs that print the incorrect electron configurations on the pastebin?

Comment: Also, there are exceptions to the Aufbau principle (like Chromium (atomic no. 24) having `4s1 3d5` instead of `4s2 3d4`). I see that it was asked in the sandbox post but was never answered. Do we ignore that issue?

Comment: OMG I swear I was going to post this exact same question...today

Comment: @Uriel [tag:status-completed]

Comment: @MDXF could you create new test cases that follow the correct electron configuration, but preserve the current one? (so new answers must golf the new version, but without invalidating existing answers)

Comment: Actually, there doesn't seem to be a consensus on how to handle challenges with incorrect information. [I posted this issue on meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14383/60043). Personally, I strongly urge that you fix the problem (but not invalidate existing answers); otherwise, all of the solutions here are technically "incorrect."

Comment: The problem being the incorrect electron configurations. e.g. `20 -> 1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p6 3d2` should be `20 -> 1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p6 4s2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>63 62 56</s> 55 bytes

```
ḊFµi@€QḤ’Ḥ
“ŒµḊuÆẓƙỊ’D,“çƥ÷£ḟ’ṃ“spdf”¤µxÇZ
¢ḣŒg'µQ€żL€K
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hji63Q1szHR41rQl8uGPJo4aZQJLrUcOco5MObQVKlh5ue7hr8rGZD3d3AeVcdIAyh5cfW3p4@6HFD3fMBynf2QwUKy5ISXvUMPfQkkNbKw63R3EdWvRwx@Kjk9LVD20NBBp9dI8PkPT@//@/oRkA)

Thanks to user202729 for saving 6 bytes with base decompression!

**Explanation**

First I construct the list `[[1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,4,5,6,6,5,6,7,7],'sspspdspdspfdspfdsp']` with the code `“ŒµḊuÆẓƙỊ’D,“çƥ÷£ḟ’ṃ“spdf”¤` in the second link.

- `“ŒµḊuÆẓƙỊ’` is the number `1223334445545665677` compressed into base 250. `D` gives turns this into a list of digits.
- `“çƥ÷£ḟ’ṃ“spdf”` changes the base 250 number `“çƥ÷£ḟ’` into base 4 and indexes it into the string `“spdf”` yielding `'sspspdspdspfdspfdsp'`. This was contributed by user202729.

The list is then take to the fist link by `Ç`. The first link does the following:

```
ḊFµQiÐ€µḤ’Ḥ
ḊF           Dequeue then flatten yields 'sspspd...'. Ṫ doesn't work because it modifies the input.
  µ          New monadic link
   Q         Unique elements → 'spdf'
    iÐ€      The index of each of 'sspspd...' into the string 'spdf' → [1,1,2,1,2,3...]
       µ     New monadic link. This prevents Ḥ from acting on the right argument of iÐ€.
        Ḥ’Ḥ  Takes [1,1,2,1...] and computes 2(2l+1) → [2,2,6,2,6,10...]
```

Now back to the second link. With `xÇ` we repeat each of the elements in each sublist of `[[1,2,2,3...7],['sspspd...p']]` by the numbers in our new list `[2,2,6...]`. This yields `[[1,1,2,2,2,2...],['sssspp...']]`. `Z` zips the two sublist which yields `[[1,'s'],[1,'s'],[2,'s']...]`.

Now to the main link. `¢` calls the second link which yields the final list of tuples described above. Assume the input to the program is 5 as an example.

```
¢ḣŒg'µQ€żL€K
¢             Calls the second link as a nilad which yields the final list of tuples described above
 ḣ            Takes the first 5 tuples → [[1,'s'],[1,'s'],[2,'s'],[2,'s'],[2,'p']]
  Œg'         Group together runs of equal elements → [[[1,'s'],[1,'s']],[[2,'s'],[2,'s']],[[2,'p']]]
     µ        New monadic link
      Q€      Unique elements of each of these runs
         L€   Length of each of these runs
        ż     Zip these together → [[[1,'s'],2],[[2,'s'],2],[[2,'p'],1]]
           K  Join this list with spaces → 1s2 2s2 2p1
```

Comment: Any way to compress the `sspspdspd...` string?

Comment: @MDXF I tried but it ended up being longer. I also tried to construct it various ways and individual parts were shorter but as a whole it was longer

Comment: @dylnan `“çƥ÷£ḟ’ṃ“spdf”¤` for -6 byte. Used [this](https://golfingsuccess.github.io/jelly-hypertraining/help-stuff.html) for base 250 integer and `ṃ` for base decompression.

Comment: @user202729 nice, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>129</s> 128 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to notjagan</sup>

```python
n=input()
d='spdf'.find
s='sspspdspdspfdspfdsp'
i=0
while n>0:c=s[i];t=d(c)*4+2;print`s[:i].count(c)-~d(c)`+c,min(t,n);n-=t;i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYlBCoMwEEX3OYW7JI2KSunCML2ICELS4EA7hmakdNOrp2kR3l@8/@Kb142GnAmQ4s5KCw8yRR9kG5C8SMVSLMefcEwKhE68VrzfKrp2o4M04WwZvHL6dDaDjU8kXtI04ty6bScuofn88mJc/UBSXJO21ABbNNDn3F@@)

Comment: [-1 byte.](https://tio.run/##LYlBCoMwEEX3OYW7JI2KSunCML2ICELS4EA7hmakdNOrp2kR3l@8/@Kb142GnAmQ4s5KCw8yRR9kG5C8SMVSLMefcEwKhE68VrzfKrp2o4M04WwZvHL6dDaDjU8kXtI04ty6bScuofn88mJc/UBSXJO21ABbNNDn3F@@)

Answer (score 7):

## [Imperative Tampio](http://github.com/fergusq/tampio), 930 bytes

```
Yöllä on ilot.Olkoon oma ilo uusi yö, jonka iloja ovat ilo"1s",ilo"2s",ilo"2p",ilo"3s",ilo"3p",ilo"3d",ilo"4s",ilo"4p",ilo"4d",ilo"5s",ilo"5p",ilo"4f",ilo"5d",ilo"6s",ilo"6p",ilo"5f",ilo"6d",ilo"7s"ja ilo"7p".Olkoon iso yö uusi yö, jonka iloja ovat 2,2,6,2,6,10,2,6,10,2,6,14,10,2,6,14,10,2 ja 6.Kun iso luku juo ison ilon,iso ilo näyttää oman yön,missä oma yö on oman ilon ensimmäinen ilo ja ujo ilo on ison yön ensimmäinen ilo,jos iso luku on suurempi kuin ujo ilo,niin iso ilo näyttää ujon ilon,iso ilo näyttää ilon" ",oman ilon iloiksi asetetaan oman ilon ilot toisesta alkaen,ison yön iloiksi asetetaan ison yön ilot toisesta alkaen ja iso luku vähennettynä ujolla ilolla juo ison ilon ja,jos iso luku on pienempi tai yhtä suuri kuin ujo ilo,niin iso ilo näyttää ison luvun.Olkoon oma muuttuja uusi muuttuja.Kun iso sivu avautuu,omaan muuttujaan luetaan luku ja oman muuttujan arvo juo ison sivun.
```

> Yöllä **on** ilot.**Olkoon** oma ilo **uusi** yö, **jonka** iloja **ovat** **ilo**`"1s"`,**ilo**`"2s"`,**ilo**`"2p"`,**ilo**`"3s"`,**ilo**`"3p"`,**ilo**`"3d"`,**ilo**`"4s"`,**ilo**`"4p"`,**ilo**`"4d"`,**ilo**`"5s"`,**ilo**`"5p"`,**ilo**`"4f"`,**ilo**`"5d"`,**ilo**`"6s"`,**ilo**`"6p"`,**ilo**`"5f"`,**ilo**`"6d"`,**ilo**`"7s"`**ja** **ilo**`"7p"`.**Olkoon** iso yö **uusi** yö, **jonka** iloja **ovat** `2`,`2`,`6`,`2`,`6`,`10`,`2`,`6`,`10`,`2`,`6`,`14`,`10`,`2`,`6`,`14`,`10`,`2` **ja** `6`.**Kun** iso luku *juo* ison ilon,iso ilo *näyttää* oman yön,**missä** oma yö **on** oman ilon `ensimmäinen` ilo **ja** ujo ilo **on** ison yön `ensimmäinen` ilo,**jos** iso luku **on** **suurempi** **kuin** ujo ilo,**niin** iso ilo *näyttää* ujon ilon,iso ilo *näyttää* **ilon**`" "`,oman ilon iloiksi *asetetaan* oman ilon ilot `toisesta` **alkaen**,ison yön iloiksi *asetetaan* ison yön ilot `toisesta` **alkaen** **ja** iso luku **vähennettynä** ujolla ilolla *juo* ison ilon **ja**,**jos** iso luku **on** **pienempi** **tai** **yhtä** **suuri** **kuin** ujo ilo,**niin** iso ilo *näyttää* ison luvun.**Olkoon** oma muuttuja **uusi** muuttuja.**Kun** iso sivu *avautuu*,omaan muuttujaan *luetaan* *luku* **ja** oman muuttujan arvo *juo* ison sivun.

[Online version](http://iikka.kapsi.fi/tampio/elektronit-golf.html)

It is a very straightforward implementation. In the golfed version I simply replaced the words with short words like `ilo`, `yö`, `iso`, `oma`, etc.

Ungolfed:

> Listalla **on** alkiot.
>
> **Olkoon** lyhyt orbitaalilista **uusi** lista, **jonka** alkioita **ovat**
>       **orbitaali** `"1s"`,
>       **orbitaali** `"2s"`,
>       **orbitaali** `"2p"`,
>       **orbitaali** `"3s"`,
>       **orbitaali** `"3p"`,
>       **orbitaali** `"3d"`,
>       **orbitaali** `"4s"`,
>       **orbitaali** `"4p"`,
>       **orbitaali** `"4d"`,
>       **orbitaali** `"5s"`,
>       **orbitaali** `"5p"`,
>       **orbitaali** `"4f"`,
>       **orbitaali** `"5d"`,
>       **orbitaali** `"6s"`,
>       **orbitaali** `"6p"`,
>       **orbitaali** `"5f"`,
>       **orbitaali** `"6d"`,
>       **orbitaali** `"7s"` **ja**
>       **orbitaali** `"7p"`.
>
> **Olkoon** lyhyt maksimilista **uusi** lista, **jonka** alkioita **ovat**
>       `2`,
>       `2`,
>       `6`,
>       `2`,
>       `6`,
>       `10`,
>       `2`,
>       `6`,
>       `10`,
>       `2`,
>       `6`,
>       `14`,
>       `10`,
>       `2`,
>       `6`,
>       `14`,
>       `10`,
>       `2` **ja**
>       `6`.
>
> **Kun** *jaetaan* *orbitaaleille* pienehkö elektronimäärä nykyisellä sivulla,
>
> - nykyinen sivu *näyttää* nykyisen orbitaalin, **missä**
>         nykyinen orbitaali **on** lyhyen orbitaalilistan `ensimmäinen` alkio **ja**
>         nykyinen maksimi **on** lyhyen maksimilistan `ensimmäinen` alkio,
> - **jos** pienehkö elektronimäärä **on** **suurempi** **kuin** nykyinen maksimi,
>     **niin**
>
>   - nykyinen sivu *näyttää* nykyisen maksimin,
>   - nykyinen sivu *näyttää* **välin** `" "`,
>   - lyhyen orbitaalilistan alkioiksi *asetetaan* lyhyen orbitaalilistan alkiot `toisesta` **alkaen**,
>   - lyhyen maksimilistan alkioiksi *asetetaan* lyhyen maksimilistan alkiot `toisesta` **alkaen**
>   - **ja**  *jaetaan* *orbitaaleille* pienehkö elektronimäärä **vähennettynä** nykyisellä maksimilla nykyisellä sivulla,
> - **ja**, **jos** pienehkö elektronimäärä **on** **pienempi** **tai** **yhtä** **suuri** **kuin** nykyinen maksimi,
>
>   - **niin**
>       nykyinen sivu *näyttää* pienehkön elektronimäärän.
>
> **Olkoon** mukava muuttuja **uusi** muuttuja.
>
> **Kun** nykyinen sivu *avautuu*,
>
> - mukavaan muuttujaan *luetaan* *luku*
> - **ja**  *jaetaan* *orbitaaleille* mukavan muuttujan arvo nykyisellä sivulla.

[Online version](http://iikka.kapsi.fi/tampio/elektronit.html)

Translation:

> A list **has** items.
>
> **Let** the short orbital list **be** a new list, its items **are**
>   the orbital `"1s"`,
>   the orbital `"2s"`,
>   the orbital `"2p"`,
>   the orbital `"3s"`,
>   the orbital `"3p"`,
>   the orbital `"3d"`,
>   the orbital `"4s"`,
>   the orbital `"4p"`,
>   the orbital `"4d"`,
>   the orbital `"5s"`,
>   the orbital `"5p"`,
>   the orbital `"4f"`,
>   the orbital `"5d"`,
>   the orbital `"6s"`,
>   the orbital `"6p"`,
>   the orbital `"5f"`,
>   the orbital `"6d"`,
>   the orbital `"7s"` **and**
>   the orbital `"7p"`.
>
> **Let** the short maximum list **be** a new list, its items **are**
>   2,
>   2,
>   6,
>   2,
>   6,
>   10,
>   2,
>   6,
>   10,
>   2,
>   6,
>   14,
>   10,
>   2,
>   6,
>   14,
>   10,
>   2 and
>   6.
>
> **When** a small number of electrons *is divided to the orbitals* at the current page,
>
> - the current page *shows* the current orbital, **where** the current orbital **is** the first item in the short orbital list **and** the current maximum **is** the first element in the short maximum list,
> - **if** the small number of electrons **is greater than** the current maximum,
>
>   - the current page *shows* the current maximum,
>   - the current page *shows* the space `" "`,
>   - the elements of the short orbital list *are set to be* the elements of the short orbital list **beginning from** the second,
>   - the elements of the short maximum list *are set to be* the elements of the short maximum list **beginning from** the second
>   - **and** the small number of electrons **subtracted by** one *is divided to the orbitals* at the current page,
> - **and**, **if** the small number of electrons **is less than or equal to** the current maximum,
>
>   - the current page *shows* the small number or electrons.
>
> **Let** the nice variable **be** a new variable.
>
> **When** the current page *opens*,
>
> - *a number is read to* the nice variable
> - **and** the value of the nice variable *is divided to the orbitals* at the current page.

The translation is approximate, I had to change the word order to make the English more natural.

Comment: wtf that's good...

Comment: Surely there is a more tacit language that has all the features of this one.

Comment: Could you be so kind as to add a translation into English so we can understand this language?

Comment: @Zacharý I added it.

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 72 bytes

```
Ｎθ≔”{⊞″I⌀⁼C$Pπ3”α≔⁰ιＷ›θ⁰«§”o⧴∨c▷⎇_'l|”ι§αι≔⁺×⁴⌕spdf§αι²εＩ⌊⟦εθ⟧→≔⊕ιι≔⁻θεθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9nnXndjzqnPKoYW71o655jxo2ez7qaXjUuMdZJeB8gzFQ@NxGkHTjhnM73@/Z/qhhF1B544ZDqw8tB8rlP1q@5VHHiuRH07Y/6muPV8@pAWnYeWj5uY3ndoK17To8/VHjlkc9U4sLUtIg4oc2ndv6fs/KRz1dj@YvO7cVaN785Y/aJoGUd009txOqcfe5HSC5//8NDU0B)

Here you have [the verbose version](https://tio.run/##XVDNasMwDL73KUxOMtWgSewU1lMpbPTQUcZuYwe3URtB4iax0w3Gnt1z127rBtJB0vcjaVuZfnswdQhL2w7@YWg21EMnZ6O5c7y3kDjXurb8it0lExTmFzFBwbF6rbgmAfc9GX@SwImU4n0kxLpn62Hul7akN0jSLMvzXCmltdJFoYvpNEGWUeE/1Hy3L0brenDwxA05UHjHtozLteUubvOHITGTKOhKcGGchxVbboYGngm7F3kWXh2OBLePvK/8tdF4DCzPV/30Ij26d0hxcHrPRwhpqsPN8RM).

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 102 bytes

```js
n=>'0010120120132013201'.replace(/./g,k=>n?++p[m=k*4+2,n-=e=m>n?n:m,k]+'spdf'[k]+e+' ':'',p=[0,1,2,3])
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

n=>'0010120120132013201'.replace(/./g,k=>n?++p[m=k*4+2,n-=e=m>n?n:m,k]+'spdf'[k]+e+' ':'',p=[0,1,2,3])

console.log(f(  1)) // -> 1s1
console.log(f(  2)) // -> 1s2
console.log(f( 16)) // -> 1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p4
console.log(f( 50)) // -> 1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p6 3d10 4s2 4p6 4d10 5s2 5p2
console.log(f(115)) // -> 1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p6 3d10 4s2 4p6 4d10 5s2 5p6 4f14 5d10 6s2 6p6 5f14 6d10 7s2 7p3
```

#### Formatted and commented

```js
n =>                          // given the atomic number n
  '0010120120132013201'       // list of azimuthal quantum numbers
  .replace(/./g, k =>         // replace each character k in the above string with:
    n ?                       //   if n does not equal 0:
      ++p[                    //     ++p[k] = updated principal quantum number
        m = k * 4 + 2,        //       m = maximum number of electrons
        n -=                  //       subtract from n:
          e = m > n ? n : m,  //         e = min(m, n) = number of electrons
        k                     //       index actually used to access the p[] array
      ] +                     //     followed by:
      'spdf'[k] +             //     the label
      e + ' '                 //     and the number of electrons
    :                         //   else:
      '',                     //     an empty string
    p = [0, 1, 2, 3]          //   initial list of principal quantum numbers
  )                           // end of replace()
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Swift](https://swift.org), <s>177</s> <s>175</s> 156 bytes

Loosly based on @Arnauld's Javascript answer

```swift
func f(n:Int){var i=n,a=0,b=[0,1,2,3];[0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,3,2,0,1,3,2,0,1].map{a=$0*4+2;b[$0]+=1;i>0 ?print(b[$0],"spdf".map{$0}[$0],min(a,i)):();i-=a}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f8/rTQvWSFNI8/KM69Es7ossUgh0zZPJ9HWQCfJNtpAx1DHSMc41hrIArEhfARpjErH6uUmFlQn2qoYaJloG1knRasYxGrbGlpn2hko2BcUZeaVaIDFdJSKC1LSlMCqVQxqwUK5mXkaiTqZmppWGprWmbq2ibW1XP9B7jI00/wPAA)

### Without the spaces in the electron groups, <s>190</s> <s>187</s> 169 bytes:

```swift
func f(n:Int){var i=n,a=0,b=[0,1,2,3];[0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,3,2,0,1,3,2,0,1].map{a=$0*4+2;b[$0]+=1;i>0 ?print(b[$0],"spdf".map{$0}[$0],min(a,i),separator:""):();i-=a}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY69DoIwFIVfhTQMrVxN@QkDTXX2GQjDRW1yB2pTqg6kz14FB@Nyfr6c4cwvMqFJyTzsJTPcdmcbxPJEn5G2gFrCqHsJJVRQD@qT1vztP63/fThM6BbUudw1RaXGPpdDoUtFR5mdnCcb@MaAze5q2LbOZdzQRJYjkID55tBjuPuOMdFxoWivMca0fixbkd4)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), <s>43</s> 42 bytes

```
#~ElementData~"FullElectronConfiguration"&
```

-1 byte thanks to ovs.

This does not work with [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6ZgqxDz3zUnNTc1r8QlsSQxWllHya00JwcolFxSlJ/nnJ@XlpleWgRUnp@nFKv2P6AoM68kOi3aUMdIx9BMx9DQNDb2PwA), so I've provided a screenshot instead.  Note that this correctly shows the exceptions, such as `4s1 3d5` for chromium (Z=24), which occurs because half-filled and fully-filled orbitals are energetically favorable (thus slightly advantaging `4s1 3d5` over `4s2 3d4`); and `5s1 4d7` for ruthenium (Z=44):

[image]

In order to get the full electron configuration, it is necessary to use the "FullElectronConfiguration" option; the "ElectronConfigurationString" option will instead provide the electron configuration using "core notation" shorthand. E.g., for Z = 16, core notation is:

[image]

where `[Ne]` means "the electron configuration for Ne", i.e., `1s2 2s2 2p6`

Comment: [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6ZgqxDzX7nONSc1NzWvxCWxJLFOya00JwcokFxSlJ/nnJ@XlpleWgRUnp@npPY/oCgzr8RBK01B30Gh2lBHwUhHwdAMiA1Na/8DAA) using the infix notation

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc), <s>260</s> <s>187</s> <s>167</s> <s>156</s> <s>152</s> <s>147</s> <s>143</s> 138 bytes

```
i,*m;f(e){for(m=L"...",i=0;e>0;printf("%.2s%d ","1s2s2p3s3p3d4s4p4d5s5p4f5d6s6p5f6d7s7p"+i++*2,(e-=*m)<0?*m+e:*m++));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU7LboMwEJQ45MCh32C5imLziHiniiH9gX5CLsjGYSUMFia9RPx6qdNEpCvt7OzsQ8PDC@fLO/S8u4oGlWYSMOzbk/uSVD21Vlkg8BSTpKE3OYxEVV/YcTbO5tw/8m0FHEAVseYUMT1CP0mCt/vEbAXCAY5NYhKdmlSnIjOZzkRucp3JXBSm0LksxMEcNPbB970kIE1YeYqW0aen/OZowaeUzYv9ilQNPfkeQFD35iIbdxHYH7UGEQFUoZghQKWt8Ydl9ho9du@xmkvF0VoDytaRJP87fZ14W49kd@53T3l25@WHy66@mCXs1C8) Golfed from the reference implementation.

StackExchange removes unprintables, so the value of `m` is replaced with `"..."`.

Here is a reversible hexdump of the program, since it uses unprintables in a string, which replaces the integer array `{2,2,6,2,6,10,2,6,10,2,6,14,10,2,6,14,10,2,6}` with the literal byte values of the integers.

```
00000000: 692c 2a6d 3b66 2865 297b 666f 7228 6d3d  i,*m;f(e){for(m=
00000010: 4c22 0202 0602 065c 6e02 065c 6e02 060e  L".....\n..\n...
00000020: 5c6e 0206 0e5c 6e02 0622 2c69 3d30 3b65  \n...\n..",i=0;e
00000030: 3e30 3b70 7269 6e74 6628 2225 2e32 7325  >0;printf("%.2s%
00000040: 6420 222c 2231 7332 7332 7033 7333 7033  d ","1s2s2p3s3p3
00000050: 6434 7334 7034 6435 7335 7034 6635 6436  d4s4p4d5s5p4f5d6
00000060: 7336 7035 6636 6437 7337 7022 2b69 2b2b  s6p5f6d7s7p"+i++
00000070: 2a32 2c28 652d 3d2a 6d29 3c30 3f2a 6d2b  *2,(e-=*m)<0?*m+
00000080: 653a 2a6d 2b2b 2929 3b7d                 e:*m++));}
```

Alternatively, you could just copy the code from the TIO link.

Answer (score 1):

## Clarion, 388 bytes

```
PROGRAM
  Map
  End
o CString('sspspdspdspfdspfdsp')
n CString('1223334445545665677')
m CString('2 2 6 2 6 102 6 102 6 14102 6 14102 6 ')
r CString(129)
Code
  e#=Command('ATOM'); Loop i#=1 To 19
  If e#>m[(i#*2)-1:(i#*2)] Then r=r&n[i#]&o[i#]&Clip(m[(i#*2)-1:(i#*2)])&' '
  e#-=m[(i#*2)-1:(i#*2)]; Cycle.;If e# < m[(i#*2)-1:(i#*2)] Then r=r&n[i#]&o[i#]&e#;Break.;End;Message(r)
```

Loosely based on @Rod's Python answer

Comment: Welcome to the Code Golf StackExchange! I hope you enjoy your stay! :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 173 bytes

A port of [@Endenite's Swift answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150476/110802) in Scala.

173 bytes. It can be golfed much more.

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY8xb4MwEIV3fsUp011xESRVBpCROnbIFHWqOhwJThyBQ40VESH/dmo3Q9Qb7u49fcN744E7Xq7NpT042LE2MCcJ3LgDVQJ@GCfrT6MdgVyMrOcbW9SCRUMSjcjFu7V8x1wUYi02RNW@/Qkq6of33Jv/l7Keh3mSNcvp5S1dVw1OlMqi0gp1ndM8WG1cZzD6mbvuXdCndDUOR7WKaM/unPXaIAv9BMhX@lWy9wvAsVXQcyTsaSzhL@rXA/umEmItkKEuhFFYbCl8PvHLLw)

```scala
n=>{var(i,a,b)=(n,0,Array(0,1,2,3));Seq(0,0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,3,2,0,1,3,2,0,1).map{x=>a=x*4+2;b(x)+=1;if(i>0){println(b(x).toString+"spdf"(x)+math.min(a,i).toString)};i-=a}}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZAxa8MwEIV3/4pHJqlxjZ2UDAYHOhaaKXQqHc5JlF6JFSOL4BD8211ZVlwI1XTfu7t34jU7OlHfn8ufw85iQ6xxi4D9QUEJneNNW5njQ7NF4TvAhQzYkZ6IHKUTlY5ejaGrSGNkMRYxltJ337mxgzjqU/ehWP5by6SiGje0KNbwbvB3WzzhBXMsglaKVmJeIAvMCoKxRirD94dXG9b2pMUwnNjz1jo@OpNZU@/VzDugIvudVKwFxeC/KRlMurs/ngtQdJe6KKRX0bBqjk0@hvE5rn89pqlEtpJ@sev7Xw)

```scala
object Main {
  def f(n: Int): Unit = {
    var i = n
    var a = 0
    var b = Array(0, 1, 2, 3)
    List(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1).map { x => 
      a = x * 4 + 2
      b(x) += 1
      if (i > 0) {
        println(b(x).toString + "spdf"(x) + math.min(a, i).toString)
      }
      i -= a
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    f(16)
  }
}
```