# Determine the Octet(/Duplet/18-electron) Rule

Tags: code-golf, integer, chemistry

Given an atomic number in the inclusive range `[1,118]`, write the shortest program/function that outputs one of `{2,8,18}` if the element with that atomic number follows the duplet, octet, or 18-electron rule, respectively.

#### Notes

- The [Octet/Duplet/18-electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_rule) rule is a rule of thumb that describes how many electrons is needed for an element to completely fill their outer electron shells.
- The Duplet rule only applies to H, He, and Li (atomic numbers 1, 2, and 3)
- The 18-electron rule applies to all transition metals (21-30, 39-48, 72-80, 104-112), lanthanides (57-71), and actinides (89-103).
- The Octet rule applies to everything else (4-20, 31-38, 49-56, 81-88, 113-118).

#### Test Cases

```
input => output
1 => 2
2 => 2
3 => 2
4 => 8
18 => 8
19 => 8
20 => 8
21 => 18
26 => 18
30 => 18
31 => 8
92 => 18
118 => 8
```

Comment: Similar: [Electron Configurations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37657), 
[Electron Configuration](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/150416)

Comment: I think there's a typo - it says the Octet rule applies to *"133-118"*, it should be "113-118"

Comment: @TheThonnu fixed

Comment: As a former chemistry major, I'd like to point out that the "octet" elements are those of the last 6 columns of the periodic table, wrapping round to the first 2 columns, to form runs of 8 elements. Element 4 Beryllium would then fit as  a duplet, but in reality Be2+ in water borrows back 8 electrons from H2O to form Be(4*H2O)2+ to become like neon, so Wikipedia calls it an additional octet element. As for the other elements being 18-electron: the actual situation with lanthanides and actinides is way more complex but changing the rules of the question at this stage will render answers invalid

Answer (score 5):

## Excel, 60 bytes

```
=IFNA(8+10*ISEVEN(MATCH(A1,{4,21,31,39,49,57,81,89,113})),2)
```

Input in cell `A1`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 22 bytes

```
Ｉ⊗§”|↖⁵Z·⁰χ⦄P↑mＭρbl∨”Ｎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwyW/NCknNUXDscQzLyW1QkPJEAhM0IElHBAjggqIk1fSUfDMKygt8SvNTUot0tAEAev//43M/uuW5QAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Most of the program is simply a compressed look-up table.

```
   ”...”    Compressed look-up table
  §         Indexed by
        Ｎ   Input as a number
 ⊗          Doubled
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
»µ7!¾∷»₄τ¦>ḣ∑∷+›²d
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLCu8K1NyHCvuKIt8K74oKEz4TCpj7huKPiiJHiiLcr4oC6wrJkIiwiIiwiMTIiXQ==) or [verify all test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwi4oyIaOKMinfCqFMiLCLCu8K1NyHCvuKIt8K74oKEz4TCpj7huKPiiJHiiLcr4oC6wrJkIiwiIiwiMSA9PiAyXG4yID0+IDJcbjMgPT4gMlxuNCA9PiA4XG4xOCA9PiA4XG4xOSA9PiA4XG4yMCA9PiA4XG4yMSA9PiAxOFxuMjYgPT4gMThcbjMwID0+IDE4XG4zMSA9PiA4XG45MiA9PiAxOFxuMTE4ID0+IDgiXQ==).

*-1 byte* by porting part of [Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257708/116074).

```
»...»               # push compressed integer
     ₄τ             # convert to base 26
       ¦            # cumulative sum
                        this results in the list [3,20,30,38,48,56,80,88,112]
        >           # is less than input?
         ḣ          # extract head, pushes a[0] and a[1:] (a[0] == 0 iff input is less than 4)
          ∑         # sum
           ∷        # modulo 2 (this is 1 iff the 18-electron rule applies)
            +       # add
             ›      # increment
              ²     # square
               d    # double
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>72 71 56</s> 55 bytes

```python
lambda n:(n<4or sum(i>n for i in b"\x04\x15\x1f'19QYq")%2*5+4)*2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3HXISc5NSEhXyrDTybEzyixSKS3M1Mu3yFNKA7EyFzDyFJKWYCgOTmApDUyBOUze0DIwsVNJUNdIy1TbR1DKCmmMJV1-UmJeeqmGoo2BoaKlpxaUABAVFmXklGpk6CuoKCjElurp2MSUKCuo6CmkamZqaEAMWLIDQAA)

(But the `\x04\x15\x1f` should be replaced with the actual unprintable characters)

Based off Jos Woolley's Excel answer.

*-15 thanks to dingledooper* 
*-1 thanks to pan*

### [Python](https://www.python.org), 66 bytes

```python
lambda n:(n<4)*2+((20<n<31)+(38<n<49)+(56<n<81)+(88<n<113))*18or 8
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYwxDoJAEEV7TzEdM7AkDotmIWjhOWgwuroJDoSshWex2cTonbyNS_A3__1X_OdnfPjrIOFld-377m1uvoe-ux1PHUiN0pSUFhlisW6k0UwZahOprCJttpHM7MzsmDVRymaYwPyfKhuHAycwdXI5IytgrqheQcw4OfHoFCQArc_zfesBEgUWHdFyEMLSPw)

Comment: In the second answer, you can save a bunch by using a byte string instead of an array.

Comment: @dingledooper thanks! I didn't think of that.

Comment: [55](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3HXISc5NSEhXyrDTybEzyixSKS3M1Mu3yFNKA7EyFzDyFJKWYCgOTmApDUyBOUze0DIwsVNJUNdIy1TbR1DKCmmMJV1-UmJeeqmGoo2BoaKlpxaUABAVFmXklGpk6CuoKCjElurp2MSUKCuo6CmkamZqaEAMWLIDQAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 42 bytes

```ruby
->m{m>3?8+5*(2&70352637804063<<-m/2+12):2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y63OtfO2N5C21RLw0jN3MDY1MjM2NzCwMTAzNjGRjdX30jb0EjTyqj2v4ahnp6hoYWmXm5iQXVNVk2BQnSWTlp0Vmxs7X8A)

Unfortunately this fairly unimaginative approach works best.

Ruby rounds toward `-infinity`, so the minus sign in `-m/2` ensures that transitions occur in the right place. This expression evaluates to `-10` for both `19` and `20` input, and `-11` for both `21` and `22` input. To get the first `18` output, we take this `-11` and add `12` for an overall shift of `+1`. This gives a final answer of `8+5*(2)` which is 18. Larger numbers give negative leftshift, which Ruby interprets as positive rightshift.

the magic number can be replaced by `0x3ffc3ffc3e1f`
which is the same number of bytes. If three leading zeroes are added to the hex number, `+12` can be deleted, but it's the same number of bytes.

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 65 bytes

```ruby
->m{n=0
" $(1:JZ".bytes{|i|n+=15<<i}
m>3?18-10*(1&n>>(m+67)/2):2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y63Os/WgEtJQUXD0MorSkkvqbIktbi6JrMmT9vW0NTGJrOWK9fO2N7QQtfQQEvDUC3Pzk4jV9vMXFPfSNPKqPa/hqGenqGhhaZebmJBdU1WTYFCdJZOWnRWbGztfwA)

Comment: Your 54-byte solution is actually 44 since it contains 10 trailing spaces...

Comment: @dingledooper thanks. It's 42 bytes now.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
>“Þœ&08PXp“¤‘§ḂS‘²Ḥ
```

A monadic Link that accepts an integer from \$[1,118]\$ and yields the rule, \$2\$, \$8\$, or \$18\$.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/uUcOcw/OOTlYzsAiIKAByDi151DDj0PKHO5qCQYxND3cs@X@4/VHTmv//DQ0tAA)**

#### How?

```
>“...“¤‘§ḂS‘²Ḥ - Link: Atomic number, A   e.g. 48
 “...“¤‘       - lists of code-page indices -> [[20,30,38,48,56,80,88,112],[3]]
>              - (A) greater than? (that)      [[ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0],[1]]
        §      - sums                          [3,1]
         Ḃ     - mod two                       [1,1]
          S    - sum                           2
           ‘   - increment                     3
            ²  - square                        9
             Ḥ - double                        18
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 42 bytes

A hash formula with a 32-bit lookup.

```javascript
n=>n<4?2:60620415>>(-~n>>1)*223%511&1?18:8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZLDoIwEADQPaeYjaYVIUz5pEEoK0/gCQhQAiEzpDRujF69snpv7d/9Mbhl9wnxOAXbBmoNNUWn6iqrVFZgaYxIfmQMyptS@aVEvGKHutbBshMELeADCJpT1OfiWMInAhiYDt6mdONZUOr55d1Cs5Dp3o9PGkUu72AFSRl9wx8)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 47 bytes

A longer but slightly more subtle method.

```javascript
n=>n<4?2:--n%16>="_468080"[n>>4]^n>29&n<32?18:8
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcbRCoMgAAXQX5FgQ2lJVoRrak/7gj2ObUhmNOIaFvt919M5X/uz2xDndS8Q3Ji8TtAGqumrrihwEq3R2adpZSnL7AljmtcbprqeoeqqF7KTyYdIQTQRNwKiDoU8lueMDAFbWEa@hImC7@GxxxkTZXy17g5Ha3YhnoKx9Ac)

#### Method

This is based on the pattern that appears when the atomic numbers are arranged by groups of \$16\$, starting at \$0\$ instead of \$1\$. We use the following condition to determine whether it's *18-electon* or *octet*:

$$(n \bmod 16)\ge T_{\lfloor n/16 \rfloor}$$

There's unfortunately an exception for \$n=30\$ and \$n=31\$ (atomic numbers \$31\$ and \$32\$) which is not golfed very efficiently, making this method overall less competitive than the one using a more basic hash.

In the diagram below, we use `+`, `.` and `x` for *duplet*, *octet* and *18-electron* respectively.

```
   | 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F
---+--------------------------------
00 | + + + . . . . . . . . . . . . .
10 | . . . . x x x x x x x x x x . .
20 | . . . . . . x x x x x x x x x x
30 | . . . . . . . . x x x x x x x x
40 | x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
50 | . . . . . . . . x x x x x x x x
60 | x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
70 | . . . . . .
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
49Þ1š•N‚Ÿи––•₂вÅΓ·Iè
```

Port of [*@Neil*'s Charcoal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257673/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fxPLwPMOjCx81LPJ71DDr6I4LOx41TAajRY@ami5sOtx6bvKh7Z6HVwCVAgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKS/X8Ty8PzDI8ufNSwyO9Rw6yjOy7seNQwGYwWPWpqurDpcOu5yYe2Vx5e8V/nf7ShjpGOsY6JjqGFjqGljpGBjhFQxEzH2EDH2FDH0kjH0NAiFgA).

A port of [*@AndrovT*'s Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257687/52210) is **20 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)** as well:

```
•¶sWü„•₂вηO›ćsOÉ6«*Ì
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOiQ9uKww/vedQwD8h@1NR0YdO57f6PGnYdaS/2P9xpdmi11uGe//9NAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/Rw2LDm0rDj@851HDPCD7UVPThU3ntvs/ath1pL3Y/3Cn2aHVWod7/uv8jzbUMdIx1jHRMbTQMbTUMTLQMQKKmOkYG@gYG@pYGukYGlrEAgA).

Make sure to upvote both *@Neil*'s and *@AndrovT*'s answers as well!

**Explanation:**

```python
49              # Push 49
  Þ             # Cycle it indefinitely: [4,9,4,9,4,9,...]
   1š           # Prepend a 1: [1,4,9,4,9,4,9,...]
     •N‚Ÿи––•   # Push compressed integer 25350987139094
       ₂в       # Convert it to base-26 as list: [4,17,10,8,10,8,24,8,24,6]
         ÅΓ     # Run-length decode the two lists: [1,1,1,1,4,4,4,...]
           ·    # Double each: [2,2,2,2,8,8,8,...]
            Iè  # (0-based) index the input into it
                # (after which the result is output implicitly)

•¶sWü„•         # Push compressed integer 766210902312
  ₂в            # Convert it to base-26 as list: [3,17,10,8,10,8,24,8,24]
    η           # Get all prefixed of this list: [[3],[3,17],[3,17,10],...]
     O          # Sum each inner prefix: [3,20,30,38,48,56,80,88,112]
      ›         # Check if the (implicit) input-integer is larger than the values
       ć        # Extract head; push first item and remainder-list separately
        s       # Swap so the remainder-list is at the top of the stack
         O      # Sum it
          É     # Modulo-2 (with an is_odd check)
           6«   # Append a 6 to this 0 or 1
             *  # Multiply it to the extracted head
              Ì # Increase it by 2
                # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to compress large integers?* and *How to compress integer lists?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•N‚Ÿи––•` is `25350987139094`; `•N‚Ÿи––•₂в` is `[4,17,10,8,10,8,24,8,24,6]`; `•¶sWü„•` is `766210902312`; and `•¶sWü„•₂в` is `[3,17,10,8,10,8,24,8,24]`.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), <strike>81</strike> <strike>76</strike> <strike>71</strike> <strike>68</strike> 57 bytes

*thanks neil for -11 bytes*

```c
f(x){x=x<4?2:0x1fffffe01fffffe01ff807fell<<20>>x&1?18:8;}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZDdSsNAEIURr5KnGAqVXTrCzqbopvkpPoeWEtJdWVijNKkshDyJN73pQ-nTuNFW6oU4N4c5w3cOzNuhXj_W9X5_2HXmWr2nhnne-8Ln86VcCE9mHC3OVIlbo53LcynK0l_RktRCZcN3wMfFpW06eKpswzj0cTRunW67dV21ur1fQQE9ocQE50gKKUUpUAbnBhOBCWEqkUgNWRyZ5y2wkbcBElmQHCgJOpt9RUcv23A1bDLdQFHCdPPQTPC8zK4QDPtlcB6Ch_gHvXMOXiu3022A-V-lpP5rtWOTPaYff3F66ic)

Return 2 for <= 3, otherwise lookup the value in the 64-bit constants, where 0 is the 18 rule and 1 is the 8 rule.

Comment: Save 11 bytes by using a 128-bit integer constant: `f(x){x=x<4?2:0x1fffffe01fffffe01ff807fell<<20>>x&1?18:8;}`

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>61 47</s> 41 bytes

```
Ia<4P2EL{P%#({\a>a}FI(A*"&08PXp"))*t+8}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSboFS7IKlpSVpuhY3NT0TbUwCjFx9qgNUlTWqYxLtEmvdPDUctZRE5NQMLAIiCpQ0NbVKtC1qIRqg-pZEWxrBzAAA)

*-20 thanks to @DLosc*

##### Explanation

```python
Ia<4        # if the input is less than 4:
    P2      #  print 2
      EL{   # else:
P           #  print the following:
 %#(        #   length mod 2 of:
    {\a>a}  #    is the input greater than this number?
FI(A*"...") #    filter the list [20,30,38,48,56,80,88,112] by the above
)*t+8       #   times 10 plus 8 
     }      # enf if
```

Old:

```python
Ia<4        # if the input is less than 4:
    P2      #  print 2
      EL{   # else:
Fi       {  #  for i in ...
  A*"..."   #  the ASCII code points of the string
            #     [20,30,38,48,56,80,88,112]:
l:lAE       #   append the following to l
     (a>i)  #   is the input greater than i?
          } #  end for
P           #  print ...
  (1Nl)     #  ... the count of 1s in l ...
 %          #  ... mod 2 ...
*t+8        #  ... times 10 plus 8
     }      # end if
```

Comment: Probably the shortest way to generate the list `[20;30;38;48;56;80;88;112]`, if you don't mind a couple of unprintable characters, is to make an 8-character string with those codepoints and use `A*` to get the ASCII code of each character: [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSboFS7IKlpSVpuhZrHLWUROTUDCwCIgqUIEJQmQVQGgA). `l:lAE(a>i)` can be `lAE:a>i`, but in this case I'd suggest instead filtering the list and taking the length of the result. Also, several of the curly braces and parentheses are unnecessary; try removing them one pair at a time and see if you get the same results.

Comment: Oh, and `t` is initialized to `10`, so that'll save a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 103 bytes

Modified from [@The Thonnu's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/257654/110802).

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1dS8MwFIbv@ytexoRks9LUlmnZBnrnnVB3tQ2JXTIjNdH0CCulv70m4oHz8HA@eLtGtnJybx@qITz39O7si6vjEMN0Uhqa2erJEt@YYOuC51Btp1itvvePPakjyy5ZcZ1dRBmhA/JVwK2IuA8oo5XRVoLfNO7HEnvF1vKrfFEuC77IJyAmfUpjmfTnrsKD97Lf1@SNPR95hZ01hA2GBKG082AG6xQC5CDEHf/fAF/hg1rLutncAAdK0@2BgPmgmeHjjP@djUnsMZl@AQ)

```scala
def f(n:Int)=if(n<4)2 else(Seq[Byte](0x04,0x15,0x1f,0x27,0x31,0x39,0x51,0x59,0x71).count(_ >n)%2*5+4)*2
```

Ungolfed version.

```scala
object PythonToScala {
  def f(n: Int): Int = {
    val b = Array[Byte](0x04, 0x15, 0x1f, 0x27, 0x31, 0x39, 0x51, 0x59, 0x71)
    if (n < 4) 2
    else (b.count(_ > n) % 2 * 5 + 4) * 2
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    for (i <- 1 to 118) {
      println(s"$i  \t-->\t  ${f(i)}")
    }
  }
}
```